# INDEX MATCH not giving me exact match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

This formula should have given me a "Correct Access" on the last row.  Instead it gives me the same result as the one before.

Here is what my InitialFile looks like
[image]

Comment: Can you demonstrate with a simplified formula? You'll probably get your own solution that way anyway... hard to tell what's going on with all the other file references.

Comment: =INDEX(*InitialFile*!$E:$E,MATCH(C5671,*InitialFile*!$C:$C,0),1)

Comment: It's working correctly... it's returning the first match?

Comment: It is working fine, but it isn't returning any additional matches.  I remember there was a way to do this with Index/Match but I must not be doing it right.

Comment: How is the formula supposed to programmatically know which matched value to return? It will always return the first match. If you have some other method to match it (possibly using other columns) -- that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is working correctly. Your [Match function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-match-function) is searching for a value in column C:C, which are to all be the same. Thus the match result is always the first row (2?). This results in your [index formula](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_function.php) always returning the second instance. So all your values in your other blue screenshot in column `E` are returning the same cell (`E2`?)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to get the last value amongst all matching values.
If i am right, then use this formula and you'll get the required result hopefully

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(InitialFile!$C:$C=C5671),InitialFile!$E:$E)
```

If you are trying to get the very first match on top

```
=INDEX(InitialFile!$E:$E,MATCH(C5671,InitialFile!$C:$C,0))
```

If you are trying to get the 2nd, third or any nth number of matching instance then add the number at end of match functions closing bracket

i.e

```
For 2nd Match
=INDEX(InitialFile!$E:$E,MATCH(C5671,InitialFile!$C:$C,0) + 1 )

For Third Match
=INDEX(InitialFile!$E:$E,MATCH(C5671,InitialFile!$C:$C,0) + 2 )
```

If you want Last Match Then you can use this 2nd formula as well, which is better when you are trying to get 2nd last, 3rd last from bottom

```
=INDEX(InitialFile!$E:$E,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(InitialFile!C:$C)*(C5671=InitialFile!$C:$C))))
```

Now if you want the 2nd last, then subtract 1, if you want 3rd last, then subtract 2
i.e

```
=INDEX(InitialFile!$E:$E,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(InitialFile!C:$C)*(C5671=InitialFile!$C:$C))-1)) **for 2nd last match**

=INDEX(InitialFile!$E:$E,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(InitialFile!C:$C)*(C5671=InitialFile!$C:$C))-2)) **for 3rd last match**
```